# How to expose SSAS custom actions in Excel Web Access

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ssas

I have an SSAS cube with custom actions.  When I publish an Excel workbook through an Excel Web Access web part in SharePoint, the custom actions do not appear to be rendering.

Is there a special check box I need to click?  Are there limits on what SSAS custom actions can be used in SharePoint Excel Services?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently drill-through and other custom actions are unsupported in Excel Services for SharePoint 2007/2010/2013...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c50e477a-7839-497a-9dba-7fd9f13b7aa0/excel-services-pivottable-report-cant-rightclick-to-show-details-once-uploaded-to-sharepoint

Looks like I'm going to have to find some sort of work-around here...